# How can I access the correct variable when given mutable variable error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through a couple of `<textarea>` elements and initializing a wysiwig editor. 
The code:

```
for( var i = 0; i <= 2; i++ ){
    $( '#textarea' + i ).wysihtml5({
        "events": {
            "change": function() {
                console.log( i ); // Can't access i here
             }
        }
    });
}
```

But I can't access the for loop variable `i` in the `change` event function. Why is this, and how can I solve it?

I've read a couple of "mutable variable" posts here but still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work. What you need to do is to define a new scope where the `i` variable is not changing.

```
for( var i = 0; i <= 2; i++ ){
    (function(i) {
        $( '#textarea' + i ).wysihtml5({
            "events": {
                "change": function() {
                    console.log(i);
                }
            }
        });
    })(i);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because change is executed async, after the loop has finished. To get a copy of i in another scope, do this:

```
var doStuff = function(i){
    $( '#textarea' + i ).wysihtml5({
        "events": {
            "change": function() {
                console.log( i ); // Can't access i here
             }
        }
    });
}

for( var i = 0; i <= 2; i++ ){
    doStuff(i);
}
```